# I have some errors on my Java app

Tags: java, forms

I have some errors on my Java app and I dont know where is my wrong code.

My errors are:

```
        org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "audi"; SQL statement:
    select id, engine, regnum, crashed from cars where model=? [22018-193]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
        at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:972)
        at org.h2.expression.Comparison.getValue(Comparison.java:255)
        at org.h2.expression.Expression.getBooleanValue(Expression.java:178)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryFlat(Select.java:544)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:655)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:341)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:309)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:36)
        at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:110)
        at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:201)
        at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:319)
        at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:158)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "audi"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:920)
        ... 12 more

        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:624)
        at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.executeQuery(CommandRemote.java:158)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:110)
        at MyFrame$SearchAction.actionPerformed(MyFrame.java:177)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My source code is:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class MyFrame extends JFrame{

    Connection conn = null;
    Connection conn1 = null;
    PreparedStatement state = null;
    PreparedStatement state1 = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    ResultSet result1 = null;
    MyModel myModel = null;
    MyModel myModel1 = null;

    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel midPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel downPanel = new JPanel();

    JPanel midPanelUp = new JPanel();
    JPanel midPanelDown = new JPanel();

    JLabel modelLabel = new JLabel("Model: ");
    JLabel yearLabel = new JLabel("Year: ");
    JLabel engineLabel = new JLabel("Engine: ");
    JLabel crashedLabel = new JLabel("Is crashed: ");
    JLabel regNumLabel = new JLabel("Reg Number: ");

    JTextField modelField = new JTextField();
    JTextField yearField = new JTextField();
    JTextField engineField = new JTextField();
    JTextField regNumField = new JTextField();
    JTextField searchText = new JTextField(10);

    String[] content = {"No", "Yes"};
    JComboBox<String> crashedCombo = new JComboBox<String>(content);
    String[] searchContent = {"Model", "Year","Mix"};
    JComboBox<String> searchCombo = new JComboBox<String>(searchContent);

    JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
    JButton removeButton = new JButton("Remove");
    JButton updateButton = new JButton("Update");
    JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");

    JTable table = new JTable();
    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(table);

    public MyFrame(){

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 600);
        this.setLocation(700, 400); 
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

        this.add(topPanel);
        this.add(midPanel);
        this.add(downPanel);

        //topPanel
        topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2));
        topPanel.add(modelLabel);
        topPanel.add(modelField);
        topPanel.add(yearLabel);
        topPanel.add(yearField);
        topPanel.add(engineLabel);
        topPanel.add(engineField);
        topPanel.add(regNumLabel);
        topPanel.add(regNumField);
        topPanel.add(crashedLabel);
        topPanel.add(crashedCombo);
        //end topPanel

        //midPanel
        midPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        midPanel.add(midPanelUp);
        midPanel.add(midPanelDown);

        midPanelUp.add(removeButton);
        removeButton.addActionListener(new RemoveAction());
        midPanelUp.add(updateButton);
        updateButton.addActionListener(new UpdateAction());
        midPanelUp.add(addButton);
        addButton.addActionListener(new AddAction());
        midPanelDown.add(searchButton);
        midPanelDown.add(searchCombo);
        midPanelDown.add(searchText);
        searchButton.addActionListener(new SearchAction());
        //end midPanel

        //downPanel
        scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 150));
        downPanel.add(scroller);
        getAllFromDB();

        //end downPanel

    }

    public class SearchAction implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String model = null;
            int year = 1908;
            String critiria = "model";

            switch(searchCombo.getSelectedIndex()){
            case 0: model = searchText.getText();
                break;

            case 1: year = Integer.parseInt(searchText.getText());
                critiria = "year";
                break;

            case 2: model = modelField.getText();
                    year = Integer.parseInt(yearField.getText());
            break; 
            }

            conn = UtilDB.getConnected();
            conn1 = UtilDB.getConnected();
            String sql = "select id, engine, regnum, crashed " + "from cars " + "where " + critiria + "=?";
            String sqlMix = "select id, model, engine, regnum, crashed " + "from cars " + "where model like ? AND year >= ?";
            try {
                state1 = conn1.prepareStatement(sqlMix);
            } catch (SQLException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (searchCombo.getSelectedIndex() == 2){
                try {

                    state1.setString(1, model + "%");
                    state1.setInt(2, year);
                    result1 = state1.executeQuery();
                    myModel1 = new MyModel(result1);
                    table.setModel(myModel1);
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            try {
                state = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                if (searchCombo.getSelectedIndex() == 0){

                    state.setString(1, model);
                }
                else{
                    state.setInt(1, year);
                }

                result = state.executeQuery();
                myModel = new MyModel(result);
                table.setModel(myModel);
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public class UpdateAction implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String model = modelField.getText();
            String regNum = regNumField.getText();
            conn = UtilDB.getConnected();
            String sql = "update cars set model = ? where regnum = ?";
            try {
                state = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                state.setString(1, model);
                state.setString(2, regNum);
                state.execute();
            }  catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            getAllFromDB();
        }

    }

    public class RemoveAction implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String regNum = regNumField.getText();
            clearFields();
            conn = UtilDB.getConnected();
            String sql = "delete from cars where regnum = ?";
            try {
                state = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                state.setString(1, regNum);
                state.execute();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            getAllFromDB();
        }

    }

    public class AddAction implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String model = modelField.getText();
            int year = Integer.parseInt(yearField.getText());
            float engine = Float.parseFloat(engineField.getText()); 
            String regNum = regNumField.getText();
            boolean isCrashed = false;

            if (crashedCombo.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
                isCrashed = true;
            }
            clearFields();

            conn = UtilDB.getConnected();
            String sql = "insert into cars values(null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            try {
                state = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                state.setString(1, model);
                state.setInt(2, year);
                state.setFloat(3, engine);
                state.setString(4, regNum);
                state.setBoolean(5, isCrashed);
                state.execute();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            getAllFromDB();
        }// end actionPerformed     
    }// end class
public void clearFields() {

    modelField.setText("");
    yearField.setText("");
    engineField.setText("");
    regNumField.setText("");
    crashedCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);
  }

public void getAllFromDB(){

        conn = UtilDB.getConnected();
        String sql = "select * from cars";
        try {
            state = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            result = state.executeQuery();
            myModel = new MyModel(result);
            table.setModel(myModel);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}// end MyFrame class
```

I thing my wrong code maybe is in sql queries, but Im not sure.. Some ideas how to fix it ?
My second task was to make a request with Like request to MySql when the user enters in the box model letters "MA" to go out Mazda and Maserati ..

Comment: Maybe model is an integer in your database. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to be the below switch block:

```
        switch(searchCombo.getSelectedIndex()){
            case 0: model = searchText.getText();
                break;

            case 1: year = Integer.parseInt(searchText.getText());
                critiria = "year";
                break;

            case 2: model = modelField.getText();
                    year = Integer.parseInt(yearField.getText());
            break;
```

Either of `searchText` or `yearField` has a `string` value and hence, when it goes into `case` 1 or 2, it tries to convert it into Integer, resulting in `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

it is throwing NumberFormatException which means the value "audi" is not a number but still you are trying to convert it into some number format.

Answer (score -1):

the error message says all:

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "audi"

you are trying to convert a string word (audi as the msg suggest..) into a number

maybe here??

```
case 1: year = Integer.parseInt(searchText.getText());
       critiria = "year";
       break;
```

Comment: Error is in this line: result = state.executeQuery(); Trying to execute the query, not during parsing.